# Google Charts Map Visualization with addresses

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Using the Map Visualization [data format](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#Data_Format), I cannot seem to be able to get a map sourced from an address string.

Geographic coordinates, similar to those provided in the example work perfectly, but addresses will not result in a rendered map.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zv5cB/) is a sample of both a functional geographic coordinate map and a non-functional address map. The address DataTable and Map declaration are seemingly valid according to the documentation, but result in the cryptic console error: "Uncaught InvalidValueError: unknown property kS".

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: [ "map" ] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaps);
function drawMaps()
{    
    var geoDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
        [ "Latitude", "Longitude" ],
        [ 40.748298, -73.985541 ]
    ]);
    var geoMap = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById("geoMap"));
    geoMap.draw(geoDataTable, { showTip: true });

    var addressDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
        [ "Address" ],
        [ "350 5th Ave, New York, NY" ]
    ]);
    var addressMap = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById("addressMap"));
    addressMap.draw(addressDataTable, { showTip: true });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is actually currently broken in the Visualization API.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-visualization-api/address/google-visualization-api/2iHPvSx8XoE/Am4Jop4QhMUJ)